# Export failed using xcodebuild command on terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, bamboo, xcodebuild

I tried to archive my project using Bamboo, but it got failed on the export command (the build and archive process is succeed). I am using these commands below to export the project:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild \
    -exportArchive \
    -archivePath $CUSTOM_WORKING_DIRECTORY/build/Integration/AppMobile-iOS.xcarchive \
    -exportPath $CUSTOM_WORKING_DIRECTORY/build/Integration/ExportedProduct \
    -exportOptionsPlist $EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST_PATH \
    -IDEPostProgressNotifications=YES \
    -DVTAllowServerCertificates=YES \
    -DVTProvisioningUseServerAccounts=YES \
    -DTDKProvisioningProfileExtraSearchPaths=$PROVISIONING_PROFILES_PATH \
    -configuration $CONFIGURATION
```

But I got this in Bamboo:

```
2018-08-01 11:16:59.428 xcodebuild[15134:2349667]  DVTDeveloperAccountManager: Failed to load credentials for user@user.com: (null)
2018-08-01 11:17:31.678 xcodebuild[15134:2349660] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f88f750aee0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=23 \"There are no accounts registered with Xcode.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There are no accounts registered with Xcode., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add your server to your team in the bot editor.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 \"No profiles for 'application.id' were found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'application.id' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'application.id'.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=23 \"There are no accounts registered with Xcode.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There are no accounts registered with Xcode., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add your server to your team in the bot editor.}",
...
```

I have tried to add these line before the export command:

```
security unlock-keychain -p password /Users/xcodeserver/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

But still got the same. Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: What is the content of exportOptions.plist?

Comment: Did you resolve issue? I have same.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because iOS distribution certificate was revoked.